# Facebook friends page

Tags: facebook, scroll, html

I want to be able to open a link to a Facebook page, open up the friends tab, and have the entire list load.  I am currently using control + end key to do this.  The page seems to load more data as you approach the bottom of the list, and I want to find out how to either open the page and automatically scroll till the bottom is reached.

Ideally I would love to have this open in VBA, where I type in my friends page URL and VBA would scroll on the page.

I can already open a webpage, in VBA, but I can seem to scroll down using vba. I am not married to VBA, so c#, Java, HTML, would all be welcomed code options.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can only get friends that granted user_friends permission to the app

Comment: I realize that, it is for my page and a friends page.  I want to see all of our friends, I'm not talking about a random page with friends blocked,  do you have any input here or just pointing out something known?

Comment: Doesn't matter. You can only get friends that grant the permission to the app

Comment: I don't think you understand,  I am opening up my friends Facebook page and selecting their friends list.  I want to see all the friends on the page without manually scrolling to fill in the page.  Ideally I will open the webpage via VBA createobject("internet explorer.application)

Comment: Scraping Facebook is not allowed. You have to use the api